# why linq query is not working in c# .net

Tags: c#, linq

i would like to understand why this below particular query is not picking up the files from the folder, whether i am doing any wrong, please advise

c# Linq Query:

```
var query = from o in Directory.GetFiles("/YourFolder", "*.*",
                SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        let x = new FileInfo(o)
        where x.CreationTime <= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-10)
        select o;
```

in the folder i holding 200 files, but it is not fetching any files, in the position of 10 if i give 0 it was pulling all the 200 files, what is the reason? please advice

file creation time is all of them 1/5/2012

Comment: Are you sure that you have any files fitting this criteria?

Comment: "file creation time is all of them 1/5/2012" thats only 5 months ago not 10..

Comment: Is the start directory for your application correct? i.e. has a \YourFolder underneath it. If you're starting in the wrong place, you'll never see it. Try debugging just the GetFiles line before you move on to the LINQ.

Comment: @Manatherin remember, Americans like to put their months first... Even then, that's still not quite ten months ago.

Comment: @andrey if files are not present in the folder,when i configured as 0 it is given an output about of 200 files nah

Comment: So what do you want?  All files that have been there more more than 10 months?  Files that have been there for less than 10 months?  What?  Right now you have a bunch of files that are 9 months old, but your query is asking for files that are more than 10 months old.  Clearly there are none that are more than 10 months old.

Comment: If you've solved this then can you either accept an answer or if you solved this yourself post your own answer?

Comment: i dunno how to vote for my question by me own @kev

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```
DateTime minDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-10);
var query = Directory.GetFiles("/YourFolder", "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => new FileInfo(f).CreationTime <= minDate);
```

Functionally it's the same - but marginally easier to debug.

Comment: I like inline linq myself...easier to write and debug, I agree...harder to read though, until you get used to it.  I also find it a lot harder to write Join's using inline.  I know you can, but I do find it rather difficult...